# How can I eliminate duplicate notifications when I have a custom notification on a Gmail label?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, notifications, gmail

I've set up a custom notification on a particular Gmail label (call it [special]).   However, when an email with the [special] tag arrives, I get a notification for both the [inbox] and [special].

The audio notification plays the first half-second or so of the mailbox notification, and then switches to the [special] notification.
In the notification bar, I get two Gmail icons, both with the same message when I slide the notifications open.

Without removing the [inbox] label from these messages, is there a way to eliminate the duplicate notifications?

I'm on 4.0.4.

Comment: As long as it is in the [inbox] you will get the notification. you could create a rule that "archives" it so it only exists in [special] and never in [inbox].

Comment: @Ryan - these are emails that require an action, I archive them when done, so I don't want to archive them by rule when they arrive.

Comment: There is no way to turn off notifications for "some" items that come in to the inbox.

Answer (score 2):

In the main screen of the Gmail app, from the "overflow" menu (the three dots in the top-right), choose **Manage labels**. From there, select a label to get a new screen with that label's settings. From that screen, the **Label notifications** setting controls whether you get a notification for new mails in that label. If you turn it off for "Priority Inbox" and "Important", you'll only get the notification from "Inbox".